# How to get response json from Spring WebClient

Tags: spring, spring-boot, response, spring-webflux, resttemplate

I've been trying to follow the simplest tutorials out there for how to use `WebClient`, which I understand to be the next greatest thing compared to `RestTemplate`.

For example, https://www.baeldung.com/spring-5-webclient#4-getting-a-response

[image]

So when I try to do the same thing with https://petstore.swagger.io/v2/pet/findByStatus?status=available which is supposed to return some json,

```java
WebClient webClient = WebClient.create();
webClient.get().uri("https://petstore.swagger.io/v2/pet/findByStatus?status=available").exchange().block();
```

[image]

I have absolutely no idea how to proceed from the resultant `DefaultClientResponse` object. It shouldn't be this convoluted to arrive at the physical response body, but I digress.

How do I get the response body with the code I provided?

Comment: "When I try the same thing", you are not doing the same thing? You aren't doing anything to the client response  e.g. mapping it, or calling the `bodyToMono` that will map the body to a type...

Comment: wow.... i figured it out

Answer (score 40, accepted):

In the form you currently have it, and explaining the behaviour..

```
WebClient webClient = WebClient.create();
webClient.get()
         .uri("https://petstore.swagger.io/v2/pet/findByStatus?status=available")
         .exchange()
         .block();
```

the `block()` starts the request by internally synchronously subscribing to the `Mono`, and returns the resulting `ClientResponse`.  You could also handle this asynchronously by calling `subscribe()` on the `Mono` returned by the `exchange()` method, instead of `block()`.

In this current form, after the `block()` you now have all the metadata (ie. from the response header) about the response in a `ClientResponse` object, including the success status. This does not mean that the response body has finished coming through. If you don't care about the response payload, you could confirm the success and leave it at that.

If you further want to look at the response body, you need to convert the response body stream into some class.  A this point you can decide whether you want to read everything into a single `Mono` with `bodyToMono` or into a stream of objects (`Flux`) with `bodyToFlux`, such as in the case where the response is a JSON array that can be parsed into individual separate Java objects.

However, in your case, you just want to see the JSON as-is. So converting to a `String` is sufficient.  You would just use `bodyToMono` which would return a `Mono` object.

```
WebClient webClient = WebClient.create();
String responseJson = webClient.get()
                               .uri("https://petstore.swagger.io/v2/pet/findByStatus?status=available")
                               .exchange()
                               .block()
                               .bodyToMono(String.class)
                               .block();
```

Here you use `block()` to wait for the response payload to arrive and be parsed into a `String`, but you could also `subscribe` to the `Mono` to receive it reactively when it is complete.

One thing to note is that `retrieve()` can be used instead of `exchange()` to shortcut the `ClientResponse`. In this case you let default behavior handle error responses. Using `exchange()` puts all the responsibility on the application for responding to error responses on the `ClientResponse`. Read more [in the Javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/reactive/function/client/WebClient.RequestHeadersSpec.html#exchange--). The `retrieve()` version would look as follows. No need to `block()` as you only care about the response data.

```
WebClient webClient = WebClient.create();
String responseJson = webClient.get()
                               .uri("https://petstore.swagger.io/v2/pet/findByStatus?status=available")
                               .retrieve()
                               .bodyToMono(String.class)
                               .block();
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you make a request with `RestTemplate`

```java
String json = new RestTemplate()
    .getForEntity("https://petstore.swagger.io/v2/pet/findByStatus?status=available")
    .getBody();
```

Here is how you make a request with `requests`

```py
import requests

json = requests.get("https://petstore.swagger.io/v2/pet/findByStatus?status=available")
    .content
```

Here is how you make a request with `WebClient`

```java
String json = WebClient.create()
    .get()
    .uri("https://petstore.swagger.io/v2/pet/findByStatus?status=available")
    .exchange()
    .block()
    .bodyToMono(String.class)
    .block();
```

Comment: because `requests` is written in javascript without a type system hence `getForEntity`, also `requests` is inherently blocking, which `WebClient` per default is not. Your comparison between `RestTemplate` and `request` is fair, because they are both blocking clients. if you wish to do a fair comparison you should compare `WebClient` to something like `Fetch` or `Axios` that returns a `Promise` and you'll notice that javascript is quite "ugly" as well. You are comparing an apple to a ferrari.

Comment: so if they are inherently different categories/types, then why does everything I read say `RestTemplate` is being depracated in favor of `WebClient`? @ThomasAndolf why are we getting rid of the spring blocking client?

Comment: Because there is no sense to maintain 2 clients, its twice the amount of work, When WebClient can act as RestTemplate, but RestTemplate cant act as WebClient

Comment: also, calling block twice is not necessary, the first one can be removed.